# Ajax: First Post great, Second Post returns Data in URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, submit

UPDATE: I resolved my issue by moving my form submitter script from the Header to the bottom of the jamesmsg.php page (the included one). This way the functions always get re-loaded and attached to the "new" form everytime the div is refreshed.

---

This is a follow-up to a previous question I had about getting only a div to refresh (and not the entire page) when submitting a form.  I've stripped out all the unnecessary javascript and code to just focus on this problem but I'm still stumped.

When I click submit the first time, the data is posted and we're good. When I click submit the second time, the entire page refreshes, the URL now shows POSTed data.. the good news is the data IS inserted to the mysql db, I just need to get this form acting properly like it does for the first click (at least it appears to do so).

My main php file is james.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id='mainpage'>
    <div id='control'>CONTROL DIV 1 ... 2 ... 3</div>

    <div id='statusupdates'><? include 'jamesmsg.php'; ?></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

so you can see I have a "Control Div" which should never change and my statusupdates div which should always be updated with the submitted form data (and a subsequent pull from mysql to show the latest updates).

jamesmsg.php (mysql credentials xxx intentionally for this post):

```
<?
$xxx = new mysqli("xxx","xxx","xxx",xxx);

$MsgText = $_POST["MsgText"];

if ($MsgText != "") {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Messages SET
                MsgDate = NOW(),
                MsgAuthor = 0,
                MsgText = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string(xxx,$MsgText) . "'";
    if (!xxx->query($query)) {
        print "error! xxxx->error<BR>query = $query<BR>";
    }
}

print "<form id=\"statusform\" action=\"james.php?L=1\">
        <textarea name=MsgText rows=5 cols=40></textarea><BR>
        <input type=submit value=Post id=uhsbutton>
        </form>";

?>

<? 
print "<BR><BR><pre>POST Variables:<BR>";
print_r ($_POST);
print_r ($_GET);
print "</pre>";
?>

<?

$query = "SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY MsgDate DESC LIMIT 5";
$msgq = $xxx->query($query);
if ($msgq->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($r = $msgq->fetch_array()) {
        print ".......<BR>";
        print "msg ID: " . $r["ID"] . " - " . $r["MsgDate"] . " " . $r["MsgAuthor"] . "<BR>";
        print $r["MsgText"] . "<BR>";

    }

}
else {
    print "no messages";
}

?>

<script>
    /*************************************
     * form submitter
     **************************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#statusform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=$(this).serialize();
        var pUrl="jamesmsg.php";

        submitFormSave(data, pUrl);
    });

    function submitFormSave(data, pUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: pUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#statusupdates").html(response);
            }
        }).success(function(){

        });
    }
});

</script>
```

You can see this in action by going to: [demo](http://uhs3.hockeysim.ca/tools/james.php?L=1)

Viewing this in Chrome's console I get no errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the success callback that you've set for your AJAX call:

```
success: function(response) {
    $("#statusupdates").html(response);
}
```

This ends up overwriting the entire form and the original `submit` event handler you set up when the page first loaded is lost. Since there is no event handler present to prevent the default behaviour, the second button click causes the entire page to refresh.

So, what I would do is get your server response to return data in the form of JSON or XML (preferably JSON since it easily integrates with JavaScript).

Right now, your server response is returning HTML back. This is something you want to avoid. The server should serve you data and then on the client side you should dynamically generate your HTML via JavaScript to show data in a readable format.

Comment: +1 for most of this, though doing HTML templating on the server-side is extremely common and there is nothing wrong with it. Templating on the server and client both have their pros and cons.

Comment: @halfer Alright, fair enough. Personally, I would advise against it for most situations but that's your call. Please don't forget to accept this as the chosen answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yep, it's a matter of opinion. Btw, I'm not the OP `:)`.

Comment: @halfer oh! Totally missed that :)

Comment: I'll be giving this a shot tonight... although I'm not at all familiar with JSON or XML...  the "html" was pretty much just from the example from another stack overflow question I had. Honestly not very sure *why* html is wrong other than what you've said, so I'll go do a little research on this on my end.

Comment: @JamesYoung Here's one reason: what if you wanted to turn your website into an iOS or Android app? Since you're return HTML, which is heavily coupled with the browser, you would have to rewrite all your PHP code. If you were to design your server-side code as a REST API, which returned JSON or XML, you would ensure that your server-side code is not deeply coupled to the client-side. Thus allowing any type of client to access the data that your server is providing. Again, you don't have to do it this way but if you want to make your operation scalable then I think it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: @Sid makes sense, however, execution is going to be my problem. I changed the data type to json (and even xml), posted and found the div did not refresh (which is a big goal of the page). When I check the DB, the data is posted so at least that part we're good on.

Comment: @JamesYoung Yeah, you will have to make a few more changes on the client side to handle JSON/XML. Right now, it's expecting HTML and if you suddenly start sending something else, things will break.

Comment: so...  not sure why I did this, but I moved the form submission script to run on the same page that gets reloaded. Sure enough, I can execute the ajax, refresh the div no problem....  wish I had done this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by moving the javascript from the Header to appear at the bottom of the included page: jamesmsg.php.

I'm now able to post and have the appropriate div refresh without the entire page always refreshing.